# Programmatically creating a json array creates error

Tags: android

Im trying to frame a json as follows,

```
{
    "session_token": "f3bb3e20d38d4624930636de074a0df0",
    "request": [
        "ApproveStatutoryMapping", {
            "statutory_mappings": [{
                "statutory_mapping_id": 3,
                "statutory_provision": "POG ActPOG Act>>State Rule All",
                "approval_status": 1,
                "rejected_reason": null,
                "notification_text": null
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

Following is my code,

```
  private JSONObject frameApproveJson() {

        JSONObject rootJson = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject innerJobj = new JSONObject();
            innerJobj.put("statutory_mapping_id", "3");
            innerJobj.put("statutory_provision", "POG ActPOG Act>>State Rule All");
            innerJobj.put("approval_status", "1");
            innerJobj.put("rejected_reason", null);
            innerJobj.put("notification_text", null);

            JSONArray innerJarr = new JSONArray();
            innerJarr.put("statutory_mappings");
            innerJarr.put(innerJobj);

            JSONArray inJarr = new JSONArray();
            inJarr.put("ApproveStatutoryMapping");
            inJarr.put(innerJarr);

            rootJson.put("session_token", "806915cf50ab4997b7b135f539fe949b");
            rootJson.put("request", inJarr);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootJson;
    }
```

The problem is that my code doesn't frame the required json. What is that Im missing. I have even returned the root json object after adding all values to rootjson object. yet the same problem persists

Comment: what do you mean by *doesn't frame the required json*

Comment: i mean it doesnt create the json array that is predefined

Comment: see your frame once again is it correct ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerJarr` is supposed to be an object not an array.

Replacing

```
JSONArray innerJarr = new JSONArray();
innerJarr.put("statutory_mappings");
innerJarr.put(innerJobj);
```

by

```
JSONObject innerJarr = new JSONObject();
JSONArray innerJarrBis = new JSONArray();
innerJarrBis.put(innerJobj);
innerJarr.put("statutory_mappings", innerJarrBis);
```

should fix the issue

Comment: `expected key "rejected_reason" is missing in the dictionary, but received: {u'statutory_mapping_id': u'3', u'statutory_provision': u'POG ActPOG Act>>State Rule All', u'approval_status': u'1'}`

Comment: then add something for rejected_reason maybe an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

[Create Json array using GSON lib its very easy to use.](https://github.com/google/gson)